# Vue - nested routes with same name?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two parent routes, each I'd like to have a child route called 'Dashboard' for consistency.

```js
{
    path: '/app',
    name: 'App',
    component: () => import('../views/App.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component: () => import('../components/App/Views/Dashboard')
        }, 
    ]
}, {
    path: '/workspace/:id',
    name: 'Workspace',
    component: () => import('../views/Workspace.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component: () => import('../components/Workspace/Views/Dashboard')
        },
    ]
},
```

Vue doesn't like this, and I also can't find a way to specify the dashboard I want using `name` rather than path. I use the name in the DOM as a heading so the user knows where they currently are. Being on the main dashboard also is visually different from a workspace dashboard.

Is my approach wrong? I know I could maybe use the metadata tag in the route to create a `DisplayName: 'Dashboard'` and use that. Just want to check if there is a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `name` **has to be unique** across all routes otherwise it would not be possible to use this: `router.push({ name: 'Dashboard'})`

Just name your `Dashboard` routes differently...

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to access a nested route, eg. `App.Dashboard` as opposed to `Workspace.Dashboard`. But like you said, appears regardless of nesting it has to be unique. I've gone with renaming the main one `Overview`

Comment: Is there any way to inject either parent dynamically? so that it would have unique routes.. I am after similar use case where multiple `product1 , product2` has `intro` page as a common route name.